# Prototype JS source what does this mean? Array.from = $A... Hash.from = $H;

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Just wondering what are the side effects or what does this mean or do. I noticed it in two parts of the source code for the Prototype JS library.

```
Hash.from = $H;

Array.from = $A;
```

any clarification would be greatly appreciated, and Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs

> Array.from clones an existing array or
> creates a new one from an array-like
> collection. This is an alias for the
> $A() method.
>
> $A() is a convenience alias of Array.from, but is the preferred way of casting to an Array.

That's what is happening in the lines you posted. The named function $A is being assigned to Array.from. So calling Array.from(iterable) is the same as calling $A(iterable). Same with Hash.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a useful answer without more context.

> Hash.from = $H;

Assigns value of variable `$H` to property `from` of object `Hash`. This is all user-defined stuff.

> Array.from = $A;

Assigns value of variable `$A` to property `from` of object `Array`. This is all user-defined except Array, which is a built-in constructor for arrays.

The side effect of modifying built-in constructor functions is the possibility that two sets of modifications will conflict with each other. For example, if prototype.js gives `Array` a `from` property and then myCoolLibrary.js also gives `Array` a `from` property, probably with a different API, one library or the other is bound to break.